Is there an SOCP presentation of power of non-convex term for this constraint $\frac{1}{4}{\left( {1 + xyz} \right)^2} \le t$?
I am a network engineer who is currently working with some network optimization problem. In my problem the term $\frac{1}{4}{\left( {1 + xyz} \right)^2}$ appears on the objective function and I can solve my problem using YALMIP and the MOSEK solver (conic solver). Therefore, I guess that the epigraph form with the constraint $\frac{1}{4}{\left( {1 + xyz} \right)^2} \le t$ must be convex and has some kind of cone presentation as well. Particularly,it might be an SOCP presentation or exponential cone presentation.
At first glance it, I have a feeling that this is a geometric programming constraint and therefore an exponential cone presentation is easy to derived.
Could anyone provide insights or guidance on deriving an SOCP representation for this constraint? Any examples or references to similar formulations would also be greatly appreciated.
Thank you in advance for your help!

If you are working in GP mode then of course this function is a polynomial (assuming $x,y,z>0$), so the standard GP exponential substitution works. As-is this function is not convex so it doesn't have a direct representation. You can ask Mosek to write out the problem it received in text format and then you will know for sure how Yalmip formulated it.

Oh how to ask mosek to write it out when I am using yalmip ?

sdpsettings('mosektaskfile', 'dump.ptf')

If in doubt see https://docs.mosek.com/latest/faq/faq.html

Thank you please close this question
